# How can I reformat a date stored as a string in VB?

Tags: vbscript

I have a date (11/1/2012) stored as a string variable called "sTemp". I want to assign this date to the string variable LessOfFiveDates in the format yyyyMMdd. I've been trying variants of the following code, but it's not working.

How can I reformat this so it will create the desired output?

```
If IsDate(sTemp) Then
    dtTemp = CDate(sTemp)
    LessOfFiveDates = CStr(Format(dtTemp, "yyyyMMdd"))
Else
```

Comment: First get rid of that `CStr()` you don't need.  Then change `Format()` to `Format$()`.  Finally, what does "not working" mean?  What results do you see, for what inputs?

Comment: @BobRiemersma Sorry I wasn't more clear. I got it to work though.

Comment: Oh, and storiing dates as strings is a silly idea anyway unless you use unambigious fixed formats like ISO8601.

Comment: @BobRiemersma I think OP uses VBScript and not VB (see also the comment under my post). `Format` or `Format$` are not functions in  VBScript, but with the use of the dotnet libraries and a `stringbuilder` you can manage it. The dotnet `string` object cannot be used in VBScript because 1. it cannot be instantiated from `createobject` (it needs initalization parameters) and 2. a `string` object directly converts to a native VBScript string whenever you use it.

Comment: This just shows how improper tagging impedes the process here. If this is not a VB6 question it shouldn't be tagged as such.  Allowing questions to be edited adds to the murk as well, invalidating the context of prior comments and answers.

Comment: @BobRiemersma Sorry for the frustration my incorrect tag caused. I've only been programming for a few months and obviously have a lot to learn. I appreciate everyone's feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using this code:

```
If IsDate(sTemp) Then
    LessOfFiveDates = CStr(Year(sTemp) & Right("00" & Month(sTemp), 2) & Right("00" & Day(sTemp), 2))
Else
```

Comment: The `Format()` call you had earlier is a much better and tidier method. Maybe if you explain how it wasn;t working, you'll get a better answer.

Comment: It wouldn't work if Region Windows settings were set for a different format. For example **English (United States)** has format of **M/d/yyyy** while **English (Canada)** has it as dd/MM/yyyy. 
Here is a matrix of output for US/CAN regions:
CANADA=11/1/2012=2012Jan11
US=11/1/2012=2012Nov01

Answer (score 3):

You supplied your own solution, upvotes for that!

In your other question, you asked for an elegant solution. An elegant solution for this problem would be the usage of the dotnet StringBuilder object. With this object, you are more flexible on your format. Because it is implemented in a string and not in code you can add the format in a configuration setup without any hassle.
Next to that, the stringbuilder will use the date based on your system locale and that is nice if you have your script run on systems with different settings for the display of date and time.

```
Dim sb : Set sb = createobject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
Dim d : d = "5/6/2007"

If isDate(d) Then
    call sb.AppendFormat("{0:yyyyMMdd}", cdate(d))
    LessOfFiveDates = sb.ToString()
End If
```

Comment: @Deanna yes, but the only way to do it in VBScript. The Format() method would be better, but is only available in VB (not VBScript). I answered another question for the OP and that question was for VBScript: [Oldest date question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093469/comparing-five-dates-in-vbscript). I assumed OP wanted the VBScript flavour for this solution too.

Comment: +1 because 1 StringBuilder and some variants of AppendFormat solve *all* formatting problems you'll ever face in VBScript. So this solutions scales better than Splendor's and avoids the crime/risk of redistributing msstdfmt.dll.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Thank you! And you're correct, I've removed my incorrect VB6 tag from this question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If one has a developer license for Visual Studio 6.0 (or subproducts such as VB6) there is an easy enough way to get a `Format()` function in VBScript without the extreme overhead of .Net:

```
'Requires msstdfmt.dll, part of Visual Studio 6.0 and
'not meant for general redistribution.
Option Explicit

Class Formatter
    Private SDFMT, RS

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set SDFMT = CreateObject("MSSTDFMT.StdDataFormat")
        Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        With RS
            .Fields.Append "V", 12 'adVariant.
            .Open
            .AddNew
            Set .Fields(0).DataFormat = SDFMT
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        RS.Close
    End Sub

    Public Function Format(ByVal Value, ByVal Style)
        SDFMT.Format = Style
        With RS.Fields(0)
            .Value = Value
            Format = .Value
        End With
    End Function
End Class

Dim FMT

Set FMT = New Formatter

MsgBox FMT.Format(Now(), "yyyy-mmm-dd hh:nn:ss")
MsgBox FMT.Format(123456.789, "###,##0.00")
```

But you usually don't need such full generality, and you can use existing VBScript operations to get the required results:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function ZF2(ByVal Num)
    ZF2 = Right("0" & CStr(Num), 2)
End Function

Private Function DtFormat(ByVal Dt)
    DtFormat = CStr(Year(Dt)) & ZF2(Month(Dt)) & ZF2(Day(Dt))
End Function

MsgBox DtFormat(#3/11/2012#)
```

Of course none of that deals with the hazards one encounters when trying to use String values as Date values.  These are subject to errors unless you are careful to use Universal Date Format (i.e. U.S. layout: MM/DD/YYYY) in your Strings and rely on implicit conversion.  The CDate() function is locale-aware and can produce bogus results if fed Universal formatted dates though.